# phpMyAdmin - Error Failed to generate random CSRF token

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I use Cloud Server (Server 2012 RC 2) This is Server Specification:-
1. IIS
2. PHP
3. MySQL
4. phpMyAdmin

and I connect through VPN (GlobalProtect)

My IP : http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

It error "phpMyAdmin - Error Failed to generate random CSRF token!"

This is my picture that error : [phpMyAdmin - Error Failed to generate random CSRF token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE7YZ.png)

Thank you very much,
Prach Konphet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case phpMyAdmin was chrooted and the function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() was not returning anything. I was able to fix it by the following command as /dev/urandom is required:

`cp -a /dev/zero /dev/urandom /dev/null {{ chroot }}/dev/`

You can test it with (output is a random string):

`<?php echo bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));`